# Url change after visiting second page in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i have created a blade  template

```
-includes
--header.blade.php
--footer.blade.php
-layout
--default.blade.php
-pages
--home.blade.php
--customers.blade.php
--customer.blade.php
```

On my customers page there is a link which is used to send the visitors to customer.blade.php . When I click on it, it goes to customer.blade.php but in my nav menu if I hover over the links I see the URL changes.
My nav is

```
/home
/customers (here are also some links which links to /customer/name)
```

after visiting /customer/name my nav is

```
/home/customer/home
/customers/customer/customers

If i use 
{{ url('/home') }}
{{ url('/customers') }} and {{ url('/customer/name') }}
```

it works. Is this a problem of me or it has to work with {{ url('') }}

Thanks

Comment: How are you using links?(without url helper). Is it `<a href="home">` or `<a href="/home">` ?

Answer (score 0):

While creating navigation menu's you have to use `url()` like:

```
url('customer/name');
```

here `url()` will return the path up-to the `root` of your application irrespective of the level on which the application is i.e. `url()` will return `abc.com` on `abc.com/admin` or on `abc.com/admin/user` etc.

Or you can also use `route()` like:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');  // Named route
```

you can call it like:

```
route('profile');
```

If you didn't use any of the above mechanism then let say you have a navigation like:

```
<a href="/home">
```

it will look for route `/home` when application url is: `abc.com/home`

and it will look for `/admin/home` when application url is: `abc.com/admin/home`

I Hope it will explain the concept.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use url('/link') and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to understand your question fully . 
But as far as I have seen , 
You have trouble with the url path . You should use url to specify the route of the each file .
Or you can use 
`{{route('home/customers') }}`

for routing the links to particular controller . It is the prefered way to use the url handling in laravel .
And also dont forget to add the name in routes/web.php file as

`Route::get('home/customers','CustomerController@Customers')->name('home/customers');`